# Promoting yourself in the forum

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I just wanted to know if it is ok to promote a video about math that I have uploaded. meaning, I'll create a post which will be a discussion about this video, where we will discuss the video, suggest improvements, and review it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for asking upfront – usually people just post such things and then complain on Meta about the downvotes...

I think this kind of post has several problems, some of which are outlined in the Help Center article [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

(even if that discussion is your own video)

Reviewing a video is also kind of subjective, and as mentioned in the blog post [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/):

> questions that are not answerable — discussions, debates, opinions — should be closed as subjective.

You can link to your video whenever it's appropriate to do so (because it helps answering a specific question), but do note that we have some [rather strict rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) about this.

Answer (score 8):

No. This is not what this website is for. If you have a genuine question that you'd like answered about mathematics related to the video, that's fine.

If you answer a question and the video is related, you may add a link, but be sure to explicitly state your connection to the production or you will attract spam votes. That being said, do not go out of your way to find answers to post the video in them, people will notice and it will be considered as spam and excessive self-promotion.